# Direct Product of Finite Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, characters

Recently, I am try to solve a problem in character theory:

[character extension about $Q_8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577220/character-extension-about-q-8)

In this problem we have that $G=G/G'\cap N\lesssim G/G'\times G/N=G/G'\times Q_8$. If $G=N\times Q_8$, then $\theta$ extends to $G$.

So I need the following result in finite groups:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N\trianglelefteq G$. Assume that $G\lesssim G/G'\times Q_8, G/N=Q_8$ and $N\le Z(G)$, then $G=N\times Q_8$.

Is it ture or not?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $G$ is not a subgroup of $G/G'$. Can you clarify what you mean by the notation?

Comment: I think the statement is not true.

Comment: Can you give a counterexample？

Answer (score 2):

Take $G=C_4\rtimes C_4=\langle a,b\mid  a^4=b^4=1, bab^{-1}=a^{-1} \rangle$ and let $N=\langle a^2b^2\rangle$.

The derived subgroup of $G$ is $\langle a^2\rangle$ with quotient isomorphic to $G/G'\cong C_4\times C_2$.  $N$ is cyclic of order $2$, central in $G$ with quotient $Q_8$. $G$ is not isomorphic to $C_2\times Q_8$ but it does embed in $C_4\times C_2\times Q_8$, in fact in $C_4\times Q_8$.